# Visual Studio Code and Autopep8 Formatter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

I am trying to setup my python formatter to autopep8.  It is installed properly, however it never as a formatting option in VSCode.

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Path": "C:\\Users\\DawsonSchaffer\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\autopep8.exe",
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--max-line-length",
        "160",
        "--aggressive",
        "--aggressive",
        "--in-place"
    ],
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "autopep8",
    },
```

[image]

I have changed all the setting. However I'm not sure what to put for autopep8.

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
},

or

"[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "autopep8",
},
```

Also autopep8 is not available in control pallet.

[image]

Thanks
Dawson

Comment: Did you type `autopep8` in the command pallete?

Answer (score 8):

This is to configure the

```
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
  },
```

in the settings.json.

You can set like this to apply autopep8 formatting:

```
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
```

[Related official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting).

Answer (score 3):

To keep it all inside your `.venv` dependencies, add the dependency paths in the `.config/settings.json`, as in this example based on VS Code [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatterspecific-settings):

```json
{
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintPath": ".venv/bin/pylint",
  "python.formatting.autopep8Path": ".venv/bin/autopep8"
}
```

This way you don't have to rely on local installs and manual tasks. It's all versioned.

Just make sure you declare those dependencies (dev is the correct type) and that you `source` the environment (AKA: activate it). This is a `Pipfile` example but anything works.

```
[dev-packages]
autopep8 = "*"
pylint = "*"
```

---

In case you're wondering how to use in-project environments I'll add some examples.

#### Venv/Virtualenv

There's no big deal here, just create it in-project as usual with the one you prefer:

```bash
# venv
python3 -m venv .venv

# virtualenv
python3 -m virtualenv .venv
```

Activation: `source .venv/bin/activate`

#### Pipenv

For Pipenv specifically you have three [methods](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-virtual-environment-location) of using in-project `.venv`:

1. Create the `.venv` directory *before* installing the dependencies (not in docs for some reason).
2. Set `WORKON_HOME` environment variable to your .venv directory.
3. Set `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` to **1** or **True**.

Activation: `pipenv shell`

Currently it is [not possible](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4467) to do it in a dedicated config file. Also, if you set these environment variables in a `.env` file they will **not work**, as explained in the same link.

#### Poetry

You can explicitly configure Poetry to use `{project_home}/.venv` by adding a configuration with the `--local` option like this:

```bash
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true --local
```

This will create a `poetry.toml` file which you can then keep as part of your code and not having to worry about it anymore.

```ini
[virtualenvs]
in-project = true
```

Activation: `poetry shell`